# Eclipse Helios and PDT - no PHP perspective available!

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

if I run my updated Eclipse Helios including PDT it will not show the options for the PHP perspective.

I run Eclipse under Windows 7 and Java 1.6.0_21. I tried to run the "-clean" option and already reinstalled PDT, but no success.

What could be the problem?

Thank you,

-lony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please check the Java build you are using. There's a reported issue with Windows 7 and Java 1.6.0_21 with builds prior to b07. See [this message](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=171988&start=0&) for more details and solutions.

If this is not the problem, look at the workspace log (Windows → Show View → Error Log) and see if there are any related errors. The errors could be related to the installation as well. If you find anything, add it to your question.

You might also want to download the prepackaged Eclipse PDT package from the eclipse.org site and see if it works OK on your machine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had an older java version but updating do not help for the already PDT patched version. The PDT bundle first show an error while closing but worked fine after I did the java update.